# $coNP$ and $\oplus P$?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Let a non-deterministic machine have at most $2^{t+1}-1$ accepting paths (highest significant bit position is $t$ and lowest significant bit position is $1$).

I want to decide if the number of accepting paths $N_{accept}$ is $0$ or $>0$.

I can ask a $\oplus P$ oracle to decide if $2^t|N_{accept}$ and $2^{t+1}|N_{accept}$ as $MOD_{2^m}P=MOD_2P$ by https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:M#modkp.

There are three different scenarios

1. $2^t|N_{accept}$ and $2^{t+1}|N_{accept}$ in which case $N_{accept}=0$.
2. $2^t|N_{accept}$ and $2^{t+1}\nmid N_{accept}$ in which case $N_{accept}=2^t$.
3. $2^t\nmid N_{accept}$ and $2^{t+1}\nmid N_{accept}$ in which case $1\leq N_{accept}\leq2^t-1$.

So $N_{accept}=0\iff\oplus P$ oracle accepts twice.

Why would the above not place $coNP$ in $\oplus P$ or at least $NP^{\oplus P}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result that $\mathrm{MOD}_{2^m}\mathrm P=\mathrm{MOD}_2\mathrm P$ only applies when $m$ is *constant*. Thus, your strategy only works if $t$ is constant, which is a trivial case. You would need it to apply to $t\approx n^c$. (Actually, the argument works for $m=O(\log n)$, but this is still not enough.)

Specifically, the reduction of $\mathrm{MOD}_{2^m}\mathrm P$ to $\mathrm{MOD}_2\mathrm P$ relies on the simple number-theoretic fact that
$$2^m\mid s\iff2\mid s\land2\mid\binom s2\land2\mid\binom s{2^2}\land\dots\land2\mid\binom s{2^{m-1}}.$$
If $s$ counts the number of objects satisfying some property, then $\binom s{2^r}$ counts the number of $2^r$-element *sets* of objects with that property.

That is, given a language $L\in\mathrm{MOD}_{2^m}\mathrm P$ of the form
$$w\in L\iff2^m\mid\#\{x<2^{n^c}:R(w,x)\},$$
where $n$ denotes $|w|$ and $R\in\mathrm P$, we can express $L$ as
$$w\in L\iff\forall r<m\ 2\mid\#\{(x_0,\dots,x_{2^r-1})\in[0,2^{n^c})^{2^r}:R_r(w,x_0,\dots,x_{2^r-1})\},$$
where
$$R_r(w,x_0,\dots,x_{2^r-1})\iff x_0<\dots<x_{2^r-1}\land\forall i<2^r\:R(w,x_i).$$
(These $m$ instances of $\oplus\mathrm P$ can be then combined to a single $\oplus\mathrm P$ predicate as $\oplus\mathrm P$ is closed under poly-time Turing reductions; in fact, even $\mathrm{\oplus P^{\oplus P}=\oplus P}$.)

As long as $m=O(\log n)$, the sequences $(x_0,\dots,x_{2^r-1})$ can be represented with $n^{O(1)}$ bits, and the predicates $R_r$ are computable polynomial time, but neither is true for larger $m$.

Comment: Why it breaks for $m=\omega(\log n)$?

Comment: The reduction will no longer be polynomial.

Comment: If you can illustrate it would be helpful (theorem $7.3$ was unclear in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759290084S). Is it related to $TC^0\not\subseteq AC^0[\oplus P]$?

Comment: Since you are looking at this paper, you can find the reduction of MOD_{p^m} to MOD_p in Theorem 7.2, which explains it quite well. I can’t make much sense of your second sentence. If your argument applied to $m$ polynomial in $n$, it would not only show $\mathrm{coNP}\subseteq\oplus\mathrm P$ as you wrote, but it would actually show $\mathrm{PP}\subseteq\oplus\mathrm P$, if this is what you are asking.

Comment: Yes I believe we can get $PP$ in $\oplus P$ if the logic worked. So is it related to $TC^0\not\subseteq AC^0[\oplus P]$?

Comment: Why $7.2$ fails at $i=\omega(\log n)$ is unclear.

Comment: So $\mathsf{MOD_{2^m}L=MOD_2L}$ holds correct at $m=O(\log n)$? By it I mean since $\mathsf{Det\bmod2}=\mathsf{Per\bmod2}$ of $\{-1,0,+1\}$ matrices is $\mathsf{\oplus L}$ complete can we compute $\mathsf{Per\bmod2^m}$ of $\{-1,0,+1\}$ matrices in $\mathsf{\oplus L}$ if $m=O(\log n)$ where $n\times n$ is the matrix dimensions.

Comment: Posted https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/48712/is-computing-mathsfper-bmod2m-in-oplus-l.